# mvn -version not working in TFS

Tags: maven, tfs

I have TFS 2012 R2 server as TFS build machine. I a using TFS 2015.2 version. I need to use maven command. I have set path for maven and Java and also updated it in path variable also. I am able to execute maven command in powershell in the server (build machine).

But when I try to execute the same in TFS build definition using powershell inline plugin, it throws me error that mvn is not a recognized command. And when I enter the full path of maven, then it does not fetch me any output.

When I give:

mvn -version

I get following error:

The term 'mvn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

When I give:

C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn -version

It gives no output

I am not sure, what am I doing wrong. It works well when I execute this directly in server but fails in TFS.

Comment: I have MS 2012 R2 server. Sorry about the typing mistake in the description

Answer (score 0):

I realised the missing part in it. This is running in poweshell in windows server. In "C:\apacahe-maven-3.3.9\bin" path, there are two "mnv" files. One is mvn.cmd and other is mvn. I was using mvn all this time and it wasn't giving any response. When I use "mvn.cmd", its working fine now.